# BigBluButton Web-Polling Module not showing

Tags: php, moodle, bigbluebutton

I  have added BigButton as a plugin in my Moodle 2.7. I need to include the polling module inside it. In my BigBlueButton on my tool bar polling module is not showing. How can I enable polling module into it. I referred this 'https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/PollingModule'. Please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit /home/yourusername/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-client/client/conf/config.xml (the path might be different for example in /var/www/...)

and uncomment the part

For HOSTNAME it should be your bigbluebutton host name.

change the file, save, then type sudo bbb-config --clean to make a fresh start, you should see the polling module in the toolbar.

regards,

Melih